# The provided GCS prefix [gs://........./] cannot be read by service account

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am attempting to create a model using gcloud but am running into an error with service account permissions that I can't figure out. The error I am get when I run this `!gcloud ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME --model=$MODEL_NAME --origin $MODEL_DIR --region=$REGION_NAME --runtime-version=2.5 --framework $FRAMEWORK --python-version=3.7` is

```
Using endpoint [https://europe-west1-ml.googleapis.com/]
```

ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The provided GCS prefix [gs://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/] cannot be read by service account service-xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:

  - description: The provided GCS prefix [gs://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/] cannot be read by service
    account service-xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
    field: version.deployment_uri

I have granted the following permissions to the service account but still getting the same error

1. Storage Admin
2. Storage Object Admin
3. Storage Object Creator
4. Storage Object Viewer

Comment: When you grant a service account, you give permission on a resource. That is named a policy binding. So, you have granter 4 different roles, but on what? The project? the bucket? Can you detail?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the service account in use currently lacks the read permission of the resource, ensure you add read access via Editor or Manger within IAM roles